# If Nodejs is single-threaded, how does streaming work?

Tags: node.js

My mental model of buffered streaming in Nodejs is that it revolves around a fixed sized queue. On one end, a producer may push arbitrary-sized byte chunks into the queue as fast as it can, until the queue is full, at which point the queue blocks until there is room again. On the other end, a consumer may pull bytes from the queue as fast as it can, until the queue is empty, at which point pulling blocks until the producer has stuffed enough bytes into the queue.

Lets say I have an enormous json file I want to convert to a csv. There are two big advantages I can think of to streaming over a naïve approach that loads the entire json file into memory, processes it into csv lines, and writes the csv file to disk all at once. For one, the amount of memory used when processing a large amount of data can be controlled by adjusting the queue size. I never need to have the full json file or csv output in memory at once, yet I can process the whole thing. The second advantage is that both the reading and writing side are working as fast as the slowest of either of them. In the naïve approach, I can't start writing anything to the csv until I have processed the entire json file, meaning the execution time is the sum of the time it takes to do the whole read and the whole write. In streaming, I can be writing while reading and processing, meaning the execution time should simply be as fast as the slowest end.

This last advantage though doesn't seem compatible with a single threaded runtime like Nodejs. With only one thread, it seems like it wouldn't be possible for both producer and consumer in a stream to work in true parallel. It seems like they would still be blocking each other, and the speed of the stream would be no better than the naïve approach above, maybe even worse if there is a lot of overhead from pushing and pulling to the stream queue. Is this the case in Nodejs? Is streaming actually slower than pulling the entire file into memory, processing it, then outputting it? If not, how does streaming improve on the naïve approach in Node? Is there any official documentation that explains how this works?

Comment: Parsing JSON and writing CSV are quite easy tasks for the CPU, your application will very likely be IO bound so there shouldn't be much of a difference.

Comment: Nodejs does use multiple threads for disk and network IO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718543/node-js-how-libuv-thread-pool-works says more.